# Let $A = (0,1]$. Then $\inf(A) = 0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am having a problem with this statement. I am trying to prove that 0 is the greatest lower bound by showing that every lower bound greater than 0 is a contradiction but I can't figure our how.

Proposition.

Let $A = (0,1]$. Then $\inf(A) = 0$

Proof.

Here, $0 < a$ for all $$a \in A$$

So $0$ is a lower bound for $A$.

Now suppose there is some $$b \in R$$ such that b is a lower bound for $A$ and $b>0$

Then, assuming $b≤1$, since $$b \in A$$ b can not be a lower bound (is this part wrong? if right, why?)

Hence $0$ is the greatest lower bound and $\inf(A)$.

Comment: how is b related to b/2?

Comment: Adding to @StevenGregory, the fact that $x\in S$ does not mean that $x\neq\inf S$. For example, taking $S=\left[0,1\right]$, then $0=\inf S\in S$.

Answer (score 4):

What properties does $\inf A$ have? Is the biggest number such that $$\inf A \le a $$ for every $a \in A$.

Now it is true that $0 \le a$ for all $a \in A$, as you say; so $\inf A \ge 0$.

Suppose now $\inf A = b > 0$; but then $\frac b2 \in A$ and $\frac b2 < b = \inf A$ contradicting the property that $\inf A$ is smaller than any element of $A$.

So $\inf A$ must be $\ge 0$ but cannot be $> 0$ hence it must be $\inf A = 0$

Comment: Now it is true that 0≤a for all a∈A, as you say; so infA≥0

Comment: why is infA≥0 here? shouldn't the inequality be the other way around?

Comment: @Meer remember, $\inf A$ is the *biggest* number with that property. So you found one number that works i.e. $0$, which is smaller than any element of $A$. But there are many such numbers (like $-1$, $-2$, etc.) you want the biggest of them. Since $0$ works, the $\inf A$ (which is the biggest such number) must be $\ge 0$

Comment: ohhhhhhhh now I finally get it... Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're right. If $b \in A$ then $b$ cannnot be a lower bound, since, for exemple, $\frac{b}{2} \in A$ and $\frac{b}{2} < b$.